# Focus the view on background

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

I have a background image assigned via `background: url("");` to the `body` element. Now, its a really huge image and I want to focus the view exactly on the middle.

To understand what I want to do, imagine the following: Open an image on a touch-screen device like an iPhone or any Android phone. Now, pinch to zoom in to the center of the image, and imagine that each zoom-level is a different viewport of another device.

I want a specific part of my image to always be in the center. So far, I have tried tried to use `background-{size,attachment,position}` but couldn't get it right at all.

My current example is at http://dev.dragonsinn.tk - and the CSS is here: http://dev.dragonsinn.tk/themes/dragonsinn/css/main.ws.php

The current image is 1920x1080, so on most screens it will center almost correctly. But my local one is 1024x786 - which looks horrible so far...

What is the needed CSS, to even make an undersized image center? I can use media queries to make it bigger later. For now, I just want to really center it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following centres your image and scales it for different viewports.

See this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) for more info on the background-size css property.

Also see https://caniuse.com/background-img-opts for browser support.

```
body {
background: url("/cdn/theme/images/bg.jpg");
background-color: black;
color: white;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I did further testing, and it seems the BG wont scroll when `cover` is used. Man, never thought it'd be s hard to have a fixed image with a concrete center...